# ERC20 Claimable Utility Tokens / InGame Currency Standard Implementation

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-20, nft, games

Can anyone point me to a resource where I can see a standard implementation of a UTILITY TOKEN (claimable unlimited supply) that are used as...well... utility in game.

I've checked multiple Utility tokens of other games and they all have customizations.

$SLP, $VIS, $sILV2, $atlas all have different implementations, so is there any base reference of a standard way? Thank you.

A helpful short explanation of of why they have different implementation or what's their purpose would be helpful as well!

sILV2 ([Illuvium](https://illuvium.io)): https://etherscan.io/address/0x7e77dcb127f99ece88230a64db8d595f31f1b068#code

SLP ([Axieinfinity](https://axieinfinity.com)): https://etherscan.io/address/0xCC8Fa225D80b9c7D42F96e9570156c65D6cAAa25#code

VIS ([Pegaxy](https://pegaxy.io)): https://polygonscan.com/address/0xcC1B9517460D8aE86fe576f614d091fCa65a28Fc#code

ATLAS ([Staratlas](https://staratlas.com)): https://etherscan.io/address/0xb9F747162AB1E95d07361f9048BcDF6eDdA9eEA7#code